# search a sub-field on mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Could be possible search a sub-element on a mongDB query?? For example,

```
find({field.subfield:'value'}, function(err, doc){...});
```

Or make something similar...

Thank you.

Comment: Quote it `{ "field.subfield": "value" }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but qoutes are needed:

```
find({"field.subfield": "value"}, function(err,doc){...});
```

[Querying documents with dot notation.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#equality-match-on-fields-within-an-embedded-document)

Comment: This is standard [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#equality-match-on-fields-within-an-embedded-document) for embedded documents in MongoDB, and referenced on the same documentation page you linked ;-)